# How can I add resilience to a minimum spanning tree?

Tags: algorithm, networking, tree, graph-theory

I have a complete, weighted, undirected graph. The edge weights are the cost of a connection between two nodes, so the minimum spanning tree is the subset of the edges with the lowest total cost such that the graph remains connected.

The MST must be connected at all times, but unfortunately the connections aren't very reliable, so I would like to add redundancy to this graph/network.

Is it possible to compute a subset of edges such that the total edge cost is minimised *and* edge-connectivity is over a certain minimum?

I can see how it would be possible by bruteforcing, but I was looking for something more practical. I haven't been able to find much about this problem, I think mainly because I don't posses the vocabulary necessary to search.

My current idea is:

- Compute the MST
- While the it is still below a certain connectivity

  - Find a node most below that connectivity
  - Activate that node's edge with the lowest weight

The reason I don't find all the nodes below a certain connectivity all at once is because activating an edge may give another one enough connectivity.

I'm pretty sure this does not yield 100% provably optimal networks, because with this method, it is possible to over-connect nodes (e.g. you activate k edges for a node, then another node activates more shared edges, making some of those k redundant). I hope that makes sense.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Of cause it is possible. (in worst case with a brute force approach). If you look for a more clever (better performing) way to do it, what have you researched so far? Share your findings / where you got stuck.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks for the reply! I've updated my question with more info. I hope that's ok.

Comment: About vocabulary: some researches about 'connected bridgeless graphs' and the algorithms to detect them could give you some ideas. But in any case, finding an optimal solution will be too hard (we could use such an algorithm to detect hamiltonian paths), so I'd suggest sticking to greedy approaches and approximations. Starting from the MST is a good idea. Did you try removing edges from the MST, and computing a new MST ?

Comment: @m.raynal Thanks a lot! That's very useful — I'll look into that. Removing the MST and computing another was actually my first thought, but I suspected that it would lead to adding redundant nodes uniformly across the entire graph (as opposed to focusing on the least-connected nodes). I'll try it and see if it yields better results in terms of total cost and connectivity.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the cost per connection added versus just the cost just the edge weight. Really if you are trying to find the edge to add for a node you want to consider if that edge adds a connection to a neighboring node that is below the threshold and if that edge does then divide its weight by 2. This probably isn't optimal either, but it is probably more optimal with reasonable runntime.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [edge connected graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) ends with, *A related problem: finding the minimum k-edge-connected spanning subgraph of G (that is: select as few as possible edges in G that your selection is k-edge-connected) is NP-hard for k >= 2.*  They then cite a 1979 paper that shows it.

Therefore I'd suggest taking a greedy approach, and tip-toeing away.

Comment: This answer brought back some memories .... there are some nice results from the 'Hungarian school' (Lovasz and his academic children) using matroids and 'kernel systems'. Especially in the case where `k=2`. You can look for papers from Lovasz, Frank, Szigeti ... but as said in the answer, a greedy approach looks more reasonable, these papers are quite theoretical.